# Can I use wordpress templates on my own non-wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress, templates

Can I use wordpress templates on my own non-wordpress website?

Comment: can't see any programming content....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You would have to replace all of the template tags and wordpress functions with static html or your own dynamic alternatives, but there is no reason why not.

Unless I suppose the theme has a license that prohibits it maybe.