# Wordpress theme for normal website

Tags: php, css, wordpress, templates

I have bought a wordpress theme. But i dont want to develop a website using wordpress. How can i use it for developing it normally with php? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `"But i dont want to develop a website using wordpress."` - then why did you buy a WordPress theme?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420527/can-i-use-wordpress-templates-on-my-own-non-wordpress-website

Comment: the client bought it for me.. anyways thanks a lot for the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can surely reuse the CSS depending how well the theme was crafted, the main part should be in the styling. The XHTML should not be a problem because it’s usually short and with many placeholder. Just replace the WP placeholder with yours own or write an adapter. Yes, if you have time, definitely write an adapter. You could even reuse it or sell it.